For loop returning same value in r
I'm trying to loop through a list of stocks in the and calculate the minimum for each stock and then place that into a separate list. I've looked up similar issues, but none seem to solve the problem I am having.
My list of stocks comes from the DOW and the list looks like
library(tidyquant); library(dplyr)
DOW_st <- data.frame(tq_index("DOW")[,1])
DOW_st <- DOW_st %>% filter(row_number() <= n()-1)
DOW_st

   symbol
1     UNH
2      GS
3    MSFT
4      HD
5     CAT
6    AMGN
7       V
8     MCD
9     CRM
10    AXP
11    HON
12    TRV
13   AAPL
14    JPM
15   AMZN
16     BA
17    IBM
18     PG
19    CVX
20    JNJ
21    MRK
22    DIS
23    MMM
24    NKE
25    WMT
26     KO
27    DOW
28   CSCO
29     VZ

I then set up the null list and the loop with the function. The loop includes grabbing the stock data using tq_get with returns a tibble with the stocks data in the time period. When I output the data
DOW_st_data <- list()

for (i in DOW_st){
  data_i <- tq_get(i, from = "1980-01-01", to = "2024-06-20", get = "stock.prices")
  min <- min(data_i$close, na.rm = T)
  comb <- cbind(i, min)
  DOW_st_data <- rbind(DOW_st_data, comb)
}
DOW_st_data 
     i      min                 
 [1,] "UNH"  "0.0299949999898672"
 [2,] "GS"   "0.0299949999898672"
 [3,] "MSFT" "0.0299949999898672"
 [4,] "HD"   "0.0299949999898672"
 [5,] "CAT"  "0.0299949999898672"
 [6,] "AMGN" "0.0299949999898672"
 [7,] "V"    "0.0299949999898672"
 [8,] "MCD"  "0.0299949999898672"
 [9,] "CRM"  "0.0299949999898672"
[10,] "AXP"  "0.0299949999898672"
[11,] "HON"  "0.0299949999898672"
[12,] "TRV"  "0.0299949999898672"
[13,] "AAPL" "0.0299949999898672"
[14,] "JPM"  "0.0299949999898672"
[15,] "AMZN" "0.0299949999898672"
[16,] "BA"   "0.0299949999898672"
[17,] "IBM"  "0.0299949999898672"
[18,] "PG"   "0.0299949999898672"
[19,] "CVX"  "0.0299949999898672"
[20,] "JNJ"  "0.0299949999898672"
[21,] "MRK"  "0.0299949999898672"
[22,] "DIS"  "0.0299949999898672"
[23,] "MMM"  "0.0299949999898672"
[24,] "NKE"  "0.0299949999898672"
[25,] "WMT"  "0.0299949999898672"
[26,] "KO"   "0.0299949999898672"
[27,] "DOW"  "0.0299949999898672"
[28,] "CSCO" "0.0299949999898672"
[29,] "VZ"   "0.0299949999898672"

I've tried indexing the data in various ways using [] but keep getting most or less the same result. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

You have created a data frame DOW_st with a column called symbol. If we first create an empty min column in that data frame, we can loop though the symbol column's values, looking up the prices, and assigning the minimum to the min column we created:
DOW_st$min = NA_real_
for (i in DOW_st$symbol){
  data_i <- tq_get(i, from = "1980-01-01", to = "2024-06-20", get = "stock.prices")
  DOW_st$min[DOW_st$symbol == i] = min(data_i$close, na.rm = T)
}


This solved the problem and got rid of a few lines and an extra object to boot. Thank you so much!

The way question was formulated makes this answer somewhat of an off-topic, but tq_get() can also take a vector of symbols, i.e. you don't really need to loop here, just fetch all results and summarise by symbol:
library(tidyquant)
library(dplyr)

DOW_st <- data.frame(tq_index("DOW")[,1])
DOW_st <- head(DOW_st, -1)

data_ <- tq_get(DOW_st$symbol, from = "1980-01-01", to = "2024-06-20", get = "stock.prices")
data_ |>
  summarise(close_min = min(close, na.rm = TRUE), .by = symbol)
#> # A tibble: 30 × 2
#>    symbol close_min
#>    <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 UNH       0.0859
#>  2 GS       52     
#>  3 MSFT      0.0903
#>  4 HD        0.0300
#>  5 CAT       3.58  
#>  6 AMGN      0.0755
#>  7 V        10.6   
#>  8 MCD       0.895 
#>  9 CRM       2.40  
#> 10 AXP       1.64  
#> # ℹ 20 more rows

Created on 2024-06-21 with reprex v2.1.0

Nice, this is much better.
